# Office Script And Power Automate to export Images from Sharepoint Document Library in Excel

Tags: excel, typescript, sharepoint, power-automate, office-scripts

I am trying to generate an excel BoQ report using Office Script and Power Automate, in which every row contains information about a BoQ item in addition to its picture.

I am getting the data from a Sharepoint List and the URL of each picture (as the pictures are in a Sharepoint Document Library) using Power Automate. All the data and rows are being filled correctly in the excel sheet using Office Script, but not the pictures.

I am getting the image from the URL and converting it to Base64 as per the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/add-image-to-workbook#sample-code-add-an-image-from-a-url-to-a-workbook

My question is how do I add the picture to the last column of the row of the BoQ item, as I did with the Array 'formattedBoqs' where the array becomes the row itself? My script is as follows:

```
    async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, boqs: BoQs[],) 
    {
      // Get the first worksheet
      const sheet = workbook.getFirstWorksheet();
    
      //Loop through BoQs and fill them in array formattedBoqs
      const boqOffset = 11; //starting row for BoQ items list
      for (let i = 0; i < boqs.length; i++) {
        const currentBoQs = boqs[i];
    
//Code Block is from the documentation linked above to get and convert the img
        // Fetch the image from a URL.
        const link = currentBoQs.imageLink;
        const response = await fetch(link);
        // Store the response as an ArrayBuffer, since it is a raw image file.
        const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
        // Convert the image data into a base64-encoded string.
        const image = convertToBase64(data);
        // Add the image to a worksheet
        sheet.addImage(image)
//End of Documentation's code block
        
        //Set BoQ item row into array then fill into excel row
        const formattedBoqs = [[currentBoQs.boqNumber, currentBoQs.location, currentBoQs.category, currentBoQs.item, currentBoQs.damageLevel, currentBoQs.repairType, currentBoQs.unit, currentBoQs.quantity, currentBoQs.width, currentBoQs.BoQlength, currentBoQs.thickness, currentBoQs.direction, currentBoQs.note /*,NEED TO ADD IMG HERE*/]];
        const boqCell = `A${boqOffset + i}:M${boqOffset + i}`;
        sheet.getRange(boqCell).setValues(formattedBoqs);
      }
    }
    
    //Bill of Quantities
    interface BoQs {
      boqNumber: number,
      location: string,
      category: string,
      item: string,
      damageLevel: string,
      repairType: string,
      unit: string,
      quantity: string,
      width: string,
      BoQlength: string,
      thickness: string,
      direction: string,
      imageLink: string,
      note: string,
    }

    /**
     * Converts an ArrayBuffer containing a .png image into a base64-encoded string.
     */
     function convertToBase64(input: ArrayBuffer) {
      const uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(input);
      const count = uInt8Array.length;
    
      // Allocate the necessary space up front.
      const charCodeArray = new Array(count) as string[];
      
      // Convert every entry in the array to a character.
      for (let i = count; i >= 0; i--) { 
        charCodeArray[i] = String.fromCharCode(uInt8Array[i]);
      }
    
      // Convert the characters to base64.
      const base64 = btoa(charCodeArray.join(''));
      return base64;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel does not allow the value of a cell to be an image, so you cannot use `Range.setValues` to add the image.

`addImage` returns an [Excelscript.Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.shape?view=office-scripts). You can use the Shape APIs to set the position of the image. Example code -

```
...
        // Get the Shape object for the added image
        let picture = sheet.addImage(image)  
        //End of Documentation's code block
        
        //Set BoQ item row into array then fill into excel row
        const formattedBoqs = [[currentBoQs.boqNumber, currentBoQs.location, currentBoQs.category, currentBoQs.item, currentBoQs.damageLevel, currentBoQs.repairType, currentBoQs.unit, currentBoQs.quantity, currentBoQs.width, currentBoQs.BoQlength, currentBoQs.thickness, currentBoQs.direction, currentBoQs.note]];
        const boqCell = `A${boqOffset + i}:M${boqOffset + i}`;
        sheet.getRange(boqCell).setValues(formattedBoqs);

        // Set the position of the image to be next to the range
        picture.setLeft(sheet.getRange(boqCell).getWidth());
        picture.setTop(sheet.getRange(boqCell).getHeight());
```

You can set other properties on the image too, like `picture.setHeight`, `picture.setWidth` and so on.